# Tag archive page not working

Tags: redirect, tags, archives

I am having a hard time dealing with the tag base page.

When I go on a tag archive, the URL is as follows :
http://example.com/blog/tag/tag1

But when I go to 
http://example.com/blog/tag

I end up with a 404.

I try redirecting /blog/tag to /blog, but then I have a redirection from /blog/tag/tag1 to /blog/tag1 which is 404 as well.

I see two solutions now :

1) Create a /blog/tag archive page that would list all tags and have a link to the /blog/tag/tag1 template (favorite solution).
I know what to code inside (in php), but when I create a new page called "tag" I am unable to create a slug using a parent page (it automatically becomes /blogtag).

2) If that is not possible, to redirect /blog/tag to /blog/ but keep the /blog/tag/tag1 structure working.

Could you please help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: How are you redirecting?

Comment: I copied some code I found on the internet into my .htaccess but it did not work, so I removed it. How would you do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your tag archive hasn't stopped working because it never existed to begin with. WordPress displays items via the main loop and this takes 2 forms:

- Individual Posts
- Post archives

If you want to list the categories or tags of your site, you'll need to create a page for that and use code be it via a plugin and shortcode, or a custom template in your theme

Such a theme template could contain a redirect by using `wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );` before outputting any markup

Comment: I tried to do it but it did not work. I created a new page called "tag" and created a php file called page-tag.php in my theme folder. Then I tried to access the example.com/projets/tag url but it was a 404 and in the wp-admin area, the page had a slug that was example.com/projetstag and not /projets/tag as I wanted to (it is impossible to add a / in the slug editor field).

Comment: What is the `projets` page?

Comment: It is the main loop. The homepage features different content, what the company does, testimonials, etc. And then the "projets" page is a kind of portfolio for which each project is a WP post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so `projets` is the root of the site? A page with a page template? A custom post type? A custom post type archive? If it's a custom post type then WP will be looking for a post of type `projets` with the slug `tag`. I think you might have muddled up your URL structure and design a little by introducing some ambiguity and clashes ( e.g. is projets/tag a projet named tag or a page named projets/tag? WP cares about these things and you need to be crystal clear about ordering and rules, usually it's much easier to avoid these issues in the first place )

Comment: The root of the site is www.example.com (the site is private I cannot give you the actual URL, sorry). It does not include a loop (it's a static page). The page /projets is the main loop (it displays all articles). Now, when I read a post, there are tags. If I want to see all posts using a tag, I am redirected to /projets/tag/my-tag, which works. The issue is that in my breadcrumbs and in the URL, I have the '/tag/' bit that is not a real page (404). I would like to avoid that, either by redirecting '/projets/tag' to '/projets' or by creating a '/projets/tag' that is not 404.

Comment: Ah, you should have asked about your breadcrumbs in the beginning

Comment: Eventually, I managed to find a solution. I just needed to declare my new "tag" page as a child page of "projets". And then update my page-tag.php file in the theme directory. Thank you for your help !